# what's the difference in using closure and private class in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const BUTTON = document.querySelector('.clickBtn');
const P = document.querySelector('.click');

const click = (() => {
    let click = 0;
    return () => ++click;
})();

BUTTON.onclick = () => {
    P.textContent = click();
};


const BUTTON2 = document.querySelector('.clickBtn2');
const P2 = document.querySelector('.click2');

class Click {
    #click = 0;

    click = () => ++this.#click;
}
const c = new Click();
BUTTON2.onclick = () => {
    P2.textContent = c.click()
};
```

```html
<button class="clickBtn">CLOSURE</button>
<p class="click"></p>

<button class="clickBtn2">CLASS</button>
<p class="click2"></p>
```

say I have a code like above, trying to manage real-time state in vanilla JS and also wanting to hide the actual data from exposing.

- I don't need multiple method
- nor do I need to copy multiple instances

in case like this, would there be any difference between closure and class except class being slightly more verbose?

Comment: Well, one thing they have in common is they're both completely useless: there's no way to get the value out.

Comment: No difference for this sort of use-case, just personal preference.

Comment: Private fields are relatively recent additions to the language. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields